# How do i assign a variable with the output of an echo?

Tags: php, class, variables, echo

I got an echo of an class value but would like to assign this value to an Variable:

```
<p class="<?echo $test="listprice"?>"></p>
```

I thought about something like this:

```
<?$testing = echo $test="listprice"?>
```

But this doesnt seem to work. Is it possible to get the class echo?

Comment: You're trying to execute two commands as one. This won't work. Try putting the two commands one after the other separated by semicolons (just like you would in normal code).

Comment: Short tags are discouraged btw.

Answer (score 2):

When you `$test = "listprice"`; you are already assigning it to the variable `$test`. To assign it to the variable `$testing` if you really want to then you would do this:

```
  $testing = $test;
  // display the new variable
  echo $testing;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to separate assignment and output:

```
<?
$test="listprice";
?>
<p class="<? echo $test; ?>"></p>
```

Comment: This works properly. But i would like to get the value of the listprice as an variable. not only the text "listprice".

Comment: what you mean under "value of listprice"? Please add more details

Answer (score -2):

Use short open tag of php `<? ?>`

```
<p class="<?=$test="listprice"?>">Something</p>
```

[**More about**](http://pk1.php.net/ini.core)

Comment: This is not what the answer asked

Answer (score -3):

it should be

```
<?php
echo $test  = "listprice";
echo $name  = "ankit";
?>
```

Comment: Well that is just plain wrong... This is not how you output a variables value

Comment: hey just see you question what are you asking